# how to do new lines? [ textarea -> jquery -> p tag ]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing something very similar to the stackoverflow question preview only much more basic.

user types in text area -> keyup shows what they've typed in preview

new lines aren't working

```
    $('input, textarea').keyup(function(){        
            var value = $(this).attr('value').replace('\n', '<br />').replace('\r', '<br />');
            $('p.preview').html(value);
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
$('input, textarea').keyup(function(){        
   var value = $(this).attr('value').replace(/\n/g,'<br/>').replace(/\r/g,'');
   $('p.preview').html(value);
});
```

Note the `/g`,which you need to replace more than the first occurance, and we're replacing only one of the returns, so you don't get 2 line returns in your preview per 1 in the textarea/input.

Comment: perfect!
didnt realise replace only changes one value,
will merge into a single regex

thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

1. To get value use `jQuery.val()` rather than `jQuery.attr()`
2. You could use CSS `white-space: pre-line` property which do exactly what you want:

   ```
   $("input, textarea").keyup(function() {
       $("p.preview").html($(this).val());
   });

   p.preview {
       white-space: pre-line;
   }
   ```